# Functions to create a simplified darts game with randomized numbers and a win condition

Tags: function, clojure

I managed to create a pair of numbers with code

```
(defn dart-throwing [] 
   [(- (* 2 (rand-int 2)) 1) (- (* 2 (rand-int 2)) 1)])


(def onetrial (dart-throwing))
```

But I do not know how to create my win condition which would be `x^2 + y^2 < 1`

I tried writing

```
(defn won? [x y] 
  (< (+ (* x x) (* y y)) 1))

(won? onetrial)
```

I expected it to check the pair `[]` from dart-throwing and check if it was less than 1 giving a true or false

I would appreciate it if I had some help, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your `won?` function expects two arguments, an `x` and a `y`. Your `onetrial` is a vector of two elements, but it is a single argument here.

You have a couple of options:

You can use [apply](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) to 'spread' the vector into the argument list.

`(apply won? onetrial)`

OR

You can rewrite `won?` slightly using [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring)

```
(defn won? [[x y]] 
  (< (+ (* x x) (* y y)) 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the same like:

```
(defn dart-throwing []
  [(rand-nth [-1 1])
   (rand-nth [-1 1])

(def onetrial (dart-throwing))
```

`rand-nth` chooses deliberately from the given collection - in this case `-1` and `1`.

And here is the problem: -1 squared is 1 - so `(+ (* x x) (* y y))` will never be `<` than 1.

So: What is the point of the `won?` function?

Or shouldn't dart-throwing return some float between -1 and 1? a selection from the range? In this case `rand-int` is wrong. It must be then `rand`.
so, instead of `(- (* 2 (rand-int 2)) 1)` it should be then `(- (* 2 (rand)) 1)`. However, `rand` excludes the upper limit - in this case `1`. One could send the upper limit to `1 + Float/MIN_VALUE` to include 1. Or one keeps it but randomly choose between -1 and 1 and multiply them with the result - then one would get 1 included ... - but it wouldn't be a even distribution ...

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see, you've got an incorrect throwing implementation, returning components `-1 | 1` instead of `-1 | 0 | 1`.

what i would propose, is something like this:

```
(defn rand-axis [] (dec (rand-int 3)))

user> (repeatedly 10 rand-axis)
;;=> (-1 -1 0 -1 0 -1 -1 0 1 -1)
```

then you just use it in an attempt function:

```
(defn attempt [] [(rand-axis) (rand-axis)])
```

and the `won?` seems to be like the following:

```
(defn won? [[x y]] (zero? (+ (* x x) (* y y))))
```

check it:

```
user> (doseq [att (repeatedly 10 attempt)]
        (println (str "throw:\t" att "\twon?:\t" (won? att))))
;; throw:   [1 -1]  won?:   false
;; throw:   [-1 1]  won?:   false
;; throw:   [1 -1]  won?:   false
;; throw:   [0 1]   won?:   false
;; throw:   [1 1]   won?:   false
;; throw:   [-1 -1] won?:   false
;; throw:   [0 1]   won?:   false
;; throw:   [-1 1]  won?:   false
;; throw:   [0 0]   won?:   true
;; throw:   [-1 0]  won?:   false
```

moreover, since the only winning situation is `[0 0]`, `won?` counld be like this:

```
(defn won? [pair] (= [0 0] pair))
```

or like this:

```
(defn won? [[a b]] (= 0 a b))
```

or even like this:

```
(def won? (comp boolean #{[0 0]}))
```